# put a false in loading whene vuex done

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

What is the right way to put a false in loading, (after the dispatch)?

Like: (I know it doesn't work)

```
this.loading = true;
this.$store.dispatch('items', data);
this.loading = false;
```

```js
<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                loading: false,
            }
        },


        methods: {

            store() {

                this.loading = true;
                this.$store.dispatch('items', data);

            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this.

#### Option 1:

Actions return promises, so make use of that.

```js
this.loading = true;
this.$store.dispatch('items', data)
.then(() => {
   this.loading = false;
})
```

I prefer this way of handling it because `loading` is defined and updated exactly where you use it.

#### Option 2:

Useful if you need to share the `loading` state among more than one component.

Put `loading` into the store's state and update it at the appropriate time in the `items` action. Then you can use `loading` in your component as `$store.state.loading` (or as a computed property).

Comment: I use option 1 but I don't see the loading. https://codesandbox.io/s/j66lo

Comment: First: don't do `Vue.use(axios)`. Remove that line from your store - you should use `axios` by just importing the library. Once you've fixed that, you'll see that logging `start` and `end` does actually work, but it's too fast for the `loading` text to show effectively. You could try setting a timeout to before you set `this.loading = false`, but it will actually work. See the changes here in `App.vue` and `store.js` https://codesandbox.io/s/promiseloading-2-li4oq

Comment: I also added `:disabled="loading"` to the button, so you can't fire off a new request until the previous one has completed.

Comment: Why need self? If self=this ? What's the advantage of this?

Comment: @Shai If you try it by updating `this.loading` inside the promise callback, it doesn't work. Basically, `this` inside callbacks is highly unpredictable. The context is specific to the callback, generally. You can do `console.log(this)` inside the callback and outside - the results will be different. Saving the context to a separate variable ensures you update the `this` of your vue instance.